# How to create database diagrams in SQL Server 2008 express?

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 express version but don't know how to generate database diagrams. When I click the Database Diagrams, it give me an error diagram tell me "Database diagram support objects cannot be installed because this database does no thave a valide owner. ...." I follow its instruction and cannot find anything wrong. Anybody can help me about this?

Anybody can recommend a free database design tool I can use with SQL Server to create ER diagram for our existing database?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the compatibility level and set authorisation:

[Database diagram support objects cannot be installed](http://www.robgonda.com/blog/index.cfm/2006/10/29/Database-diagram-support-objects-cannot-be-installed)

Comment: how to escape character '\' in the login replacement of the SQL